# why doesn't read() work after scanf()?

Tags: c, posix

OK this is a stupid question, I am sure I "should" know this but somehow I don't...

`FILE` structure wraps file descriptor, so if I `fscanf` that should advance the file descriptor.

But for this program compiled to `foobar`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    char c;

    scanf("%c", &c);
    printf("scanned %c\n", c);

    read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1);
    printf("read %c\n", c);

    read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1);
    printf("read %c\n", c);
}

>echo bcd | ./foobar
scanned b
read b
read b
```

appears the file descriptor did not advance, because the first `read` reads `b`.  What is even more surprising, the second one also reads `b` (even though, if I omit the `scanf`, then first `read` reads `b` and the second one, `c`).

I am sure this is obvious and I am really embarrased to ask why.  I just never followed `scanf` with `read` before.

I know `scanf` is a bad idea overall, but in my case it is OK because I control the other end of the pipe, and it is convenient for me to do this sequence.

Comment: Are you sure those calls to read succeeded? If they failed, they’d leave c unchanged.

Comment: You don't know *what* those reads did, as you haven't done anything with the return value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `stdin` stream will itself perform a `read` to fill an entire buffer, which is likely thousands of characters wide.  This leaves nothing for your `read` system calls. `scanf` just pulls characters from that buffer.

Your subsequent `read` system calls are actually returning 0 (no bytes read due to end of file) and not putting any data in `c`, which therefore retains its value `'b'`. Your program is oblivious to the situation because it isn't checking the return value.

Comment: In other words, there's a buffer overflow because he's putting all of stdin in the single char?

Comment: @Kaz well, I did check the return value before, and it was 1, so for clarity I did not include that in the program above.  Let me see what is going on.  Thank you.

Comment: @synchronizer The buffer is hidden inside the stream; it will snarf the entire small input being given here. The `scanf` extracts the first character from that. The `read` calls access the underlying operating system file descriptor; but that has no more input. All of it went to the stream buffer.

Comment: @Kaz OK sorry I remembered wrong, I did not check the return value previously, I just called `perror()` which succeeded of course, so I assumed, the characters were read... :) Yes 0 characters were read, success.  Thank you.

Comment: Also, try setting `stdin` unbuffered, e,g, with `setbuf(stdin, NULL)`.

Comment: @synchronizer No. A return value of 1 from `read()` indicates that one byte was transferred. `read()` does not return a boolean.